# Can I change the column that uniq -c automatically defaults to in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, uniq

I've got a file with the following columns:

```
David Smith    Bronze
Henry Jackson  Silver
David Smith    Bronze
Angela Wright  Gold
Angela Wright  Gold
David Smith    Gold
David Smith    Bronze
```

I've tried writing this code:

```
awk -F ',' '{if($6 == "name") print $6, $1}' filename.csv | sort | uniq -c
```

My output is:

```
4   David Smith   
2   Angela Wright 
1   Henry Jackson
```

Is there anyway to reverse the columns so that the names appear in the first column and the number of awards they've received appears in the 2nd column?

Comment: Please post your complete file, `$6` isn't even visible here

Comment: Do you want the first (given) name or the second (family) name in the first column? Are you then discarding the other name?

Answer (score 1):

awk can do this:

```
awk '{a[$1FS$2]++}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file
```

If you want it sorted you can either use pipe and sort or use awk's own array sort function

Comment: I think only GNU awk has the `asort()` function.

Comment: Yes I keep forgetting that people like to use some of the other versions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas, one with sed, the other with awk:

```
$ cat names.txt
David Smith
Henry Jackson
David Smith
Angela Wright
Angela Wright
David Smith
David Smith

$ uniq -c names.txt
   1 David Smith
   1 Henry Jackson
   1 David Smith
   2 Angela Wright
   2 David Smith

$ uniq -c names.txt | sed -E 's/([0-9]+) (.*$)/\2 \1/'
   David Smith 1
   Henry Jackson 1
   David Smith 1
   Angela Wright 2
   David Smith 2

$ uniq -c names.txt | awk '{count=$1; for (i=1; i<NF; ++i) $i = $(i+1); $NF=count}1'
David Smith 1
Henry Jackson 1
David Smith 1
Angela Wright 2
David Smith 2
```

If you want to make it pretty you can use a non-space delimiter between the names and count and pipe to column:

```
$ uniq -c names.txt | sed -E 's/([0-9]+) (.*$)/\2|\1/' | column -t -s \|     
David Smith    1
Henry Jackson  1
David Smith    1
Angela Wright  2
David Smith    2
```